# Jenkins Executor Starvation on CloudBees

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, hubot

I have setup jobs correctly using Jenkins on Cloudbees, Janky, and Hubot. Hubot and Janky work and are pushing the jobs to the Jenkins server.

The job has been sitting in the Jenkins queue for over an hour now. I don't see anywhere to configure the # of executors and this is a completely default instance from Cloudbees.

Is the CloudBees service just taking a while or is something misconfigured?

Comment: Are you on the free tier or for pay? It may be that your instance has fallen out of sync (if restarting your instance solves the issue Jenkins > Manage > Restart, then your instance fell out of sync). Also have you any build minutes left (if on free tier). The sync issue happens if your instance hasn't been restarted for a while.

Comment: It is a free plan, but the instance still has 300 minutes left. I've restarted the instance and that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Send an email with the instance URL to support at cloudbees dot com. We'll take a look and see what's wrong, don't forget to mention this question and say I recommended restarting and that didn't fix it.

Comment: @stephen I sent an email as you suggested, but I hadn't heard from Cloudbees until the answer was just submitted below.

Comment: Very strange. I didn't see the support ticket. I'll investigate why the response was sub-par (in terms of a delay - Ben's answer is spot on) IMHO

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem in early March caused by the build containers failing to start cleanly at times.

The root cause was a kernel oops that was occurring in the build container as it launched.

This has since been resolved, and you should not experience these long pauses waiting for an executor.

Anything more than 10 minutes is definitely a bug, and typically more than about 5s is unusual (although when a lot of jobs are launched simultaneously the time to get a container can be on the order of around 3 minutes).